# Is there a way to ignore some (but not all) remote branches using git-svn?

Tags: git, git-svn

I'm working with an svn repo that has about 10 branches that are each about 4 gigs in size, and it seems that when I run fetch using git-svn it wants to fetch ALL of these branches. I really only personally work with two of them, so how can I just fetch those two branches and ignore the rest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer my own question, in your .git/config file, you can edit the configuration of the [svn-remote "svn"] branches section.

In my case, I edited the branches configuration from:

```
branches = engine/branch/*:refs/remotes/*
```

To

```
branches = engine/branch/{the_one_repository_i_actually_wanted}:refs/remotes/*
```

The {whatever} section replaces a glob and you can have a comma-separated list of patterns for stuff you actually want to track instead.