# How do Git SVN ignore-paths work (ignoring daily build tags)?

Tags: git, git-svn, msysgit

I am trying clone an svn repository using git svn.  The repository has daily builds tagged which I want to ignore.  I am trying to use the "ignore-paths" option to do that, but I am still getting the daily build tags as branches in my repository.

A very recent and similar (but so far unanswered) question is here:
[How to git svn fetch only branches/tags with certain patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6915418/how-to-git-svn-fetch-only-branches-tags-with-certain-patterns)

#### Repository Layout - https://test.kuali.org/svn/rice

General Repository Structure

- branches

  - Branch 1
- Ignore Directory 1
- Ignore Directory 1
- tags

  - Tag 1
  - Tag 2
  - old

    - Old Tag 1
    - Old Tag 2
  - builds

    - Daily build 1
    - Daily build 2
- trunk

#### What I have Tried

I am not that great at regular expressions, and they might be wrong, but here is what I've tried:

This was just a modified version of something I found in the git svn documentation:

```
git svn clone -r15709:HEAD --prefix=svn/ --stdlayout --no-follow-parent --ignore-paths="^[^/]+/(?:tags/builds|tags/old|branches)" https://test.kuali.org/svn/rice
```

This was me trying to simplify:

```
git svn clone -r15709:HEAD --prefix=svn/ --stdlayout --no-follow-parent --ignore-paths="(old|builds)" https://test.kuali.org/svn/rice rice-full
```

Desperation... (and adding some other paths I didn't need)

```
git svn clone -r15711:HEAD --prefix=svn/ --stdlayout --ignore-paths="^[^/]+/(?:builds|old)|inactive|rice-functional-tests|sandbox|tools" https://test.kuali.org/svn/rice
```

Then I switched to a more recent revision so it would finish sooner and tried ignoring all branches and tags for a test. This one seemed not to get any branches and tags, but it also never finished.  It seemed to freeze (at least, it ran longer than I thought it should have for only getting a day or two of history):

```
git svn clone -r21846:HEAD --prefix=svn/ --stdlayout --ignore-paths="^tags*|^branches*" https://test.kuali.org/svn/rice
```

The last one I tried was:

```
git svn clone -r15711:HEAD --prefix=svn/ --stdlayout --ignore-paths="^tags/old*|^tags/builds*|^inactive*|^rice-functional-tests*|^sandbox*|^tools*" https://test.kuali.org/svn/rice
```

#### General Thoughts and Questions

1. I'm not sure exactly what the ignore-paths regular expression is matching against.  Is it the relative path of the svn repository (tags/builds/Daily build 1)? Is it evaluated for each file in the project (tags/builds/Daily build 1/file 1, tags/builds/Daily build 1/file 2) or just at the branch/tag level (tags/builds/Daily build 1)? Does it include the repository base url (https://test.kuali.org/svn/rice/tags/builds/Daily build 1)?
2. Is there something I should be doing other than --stdlayout (specifying a regular expression for the tags that would get what I want)?
3. I am only interested in trunk and certain release tags.  Is there a better way to get those?  I have tried cloning with only trunk, then adding a "fetch=" in the config to add only the tags I care about, then fetch the revision those were tagged from, but when I look at the result in git gui (visualize all branches) the two tags show up as floating with a single commit (not tied to trunk or each other).

Not sure if it is relavant, but I am using msysgit (git version 1.7.3.1.msysgit.0) on a windows 7 64 bit machine.

Long question, I know... I just wanted to be thorough.

Comment: did you ever find a soulution to this?

Answer (score 5):

It might be easier to just clone the trunk and nothing else (`git svn clone -T http://path/to/trunk`), and then add the specific tags and branches you want by modifying the config file and doing `git svn fetch`es.

Comment: I had tried that before but the two branches ended up floating and not connected to trunk.  It had been a while since I did it, so I decided to try again following this as a guide: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/296975/how-do-i-tell-git-svn-about-a-remote-branch-created-after-i-fetched-the-repo - I got the same floating branches again.  I even followed your answer to try to fix it but in step 3 of your answer there my diff is not empty.

Comment: I wonder if something in their repository is causing a problem for git svn.  I followed their history back on trunk (with their fishey) to find where another tag was created off trunk but  it didn't go back as far as the tag.  The earliest commit I found on trunk had a message: "Trunk is dead, long live Trunk. Trunk shall be resurrected from its ashes as the phoenix."